# C++: Regex library with TDM GCC

Tags: c++, regex, gcc

When I include the regex library `#include <regex>` with TDM GCC compiler (-std = c++11) I get this error:

[image]

And my compiler settings are:

[image]

How I can run regex library with TDM GCC compiler?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of GCC ? TDM is currently on  5.1.0 and I don't think this version of GCC has a working regex.  MinGW has more recent version(s) of GCC.

Comment: I have tried the MinGW compiler and the problem remains.. + the MinGW doesn't recognize functions like "stoi ,stod.. etc"

Comment: For unexplained reason if i create a simple project with #include <regex> and call std::regex_match etc , the program runs...

Comment: Please paste your error and compiler settings into the question instead of linking to images.

Comment: the lines of code are  4000..